# PHP username session variable not saving if the username includes a number

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I searched for this question but couldn't find it.

I have made a create user page that will allow the user to create an account on my page using a username.  Usernames can be any combination of letters and numbers.  When they create the user, it is supposed to call the same page, then redirect the user to the main page when it sees that the session variable is now set.

When I create a user with only letters in the username, it works fine and redirects them to the index page.  However, when I create a user such as "student1" it will not set the session variable and therefore not redirect them.

You can try it yourself at http://collinmath.com/accounts/create.php to see what I mean.  (Just don't use real info since I haven't set up the SSL yet)

```
<?php

// call the register() function if register_btn is clicked
if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    // Set variables equal to POST data
    $login_name = $_POST['username'];
    $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $role = $_POST['role'];
    $pwd1 = $_POST['password_1'];
    $pwd2 = $_POST['password_2'];
    register();
}

// Register function will check the input and add the user if
// the input is accepted
function register() {

global $login_name;
global $first_name;
global $last_name;
global $email;
global $role;
global $errors;
global $connection;
global $pwd1;
global $pwd2;
global $hostname;
global $username;
global $password;
global $dbname;

// Connect to database
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($connection, $dbname);

// Check that username contains only letters and number
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $login_name)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username must contain only letters and/or numbers");
} else {
    $login_name = strtolower($login_name);
}

// Sanitize SQL data
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $first_name);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $last_name);

// Validate registration input and generate error log if there are issues

    // Check if username is taken or empty
    if (strlen($login_name) > 4) {
        $query = "SELECT `User_Login` AS `Login` FROM `CMP_Users` WHERE `User_Login`=?";

        $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $login_name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        if ($row[Login]) {
            array_push($errors, "That username is taken");
        } 
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Username must be at least 5 characters long");
    };

    if (strlen($login_name) > 16) {
        array_push($errors, "Username must be 16 characters or less");
    }

    // Check First name
    if ($first_name) {
        if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z\'\-\s]/', $first_name) || !preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/i', $first_name)) {
            array_push($errors, "First Name is not valid");
        }
        if (strlen($first_name) > 15) {
            array_push($errors, "First name must be 15 characters or less");
        }
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Must enter a first name");
    }

    //Check Last name
    if ($last_name) {
        if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z\'\-\s]/', $last_name) || !preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/i', $last_name)) {
            array_push($errors, "Last Name is not valid");
        }
        if (strlen($last_name) > 25) {
            array_push($errors, "Last name must be 25 characters or less");
        }
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Must enter a last name");
    }

    // Validate e-mail
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        array_push($errors, "Please enter a valid e-mail address");
    }

    if (strlen($email) > 50) {
        array_push($errors, "E-mail address must be 50 characters or less");
    }

    // Check if role is legal
    $role_value = 0;
    if ($role == 'student') {
        $role_value = 1;
    } else if ($role == 'teacher') {
        $role_value = 2;
    } else {
        array_push ($errors, "No role selected");
    }

    // Check if passwords match
    if ($pwd1 != $pwd2) {
        array_push($errors, "Passwords do not match");
    } else {
        // Check if passwords meet criteria
        if (!preg_match('/\W/', $pwd1) || !preg_match('/[0-9]/', $pwd1) ||
        strlen($pwd1) < 10) {
            array_push($errors, "Password is not valid");
        }
    }

// If there are no errors, commit results to DB and create session

if (empty($errors)) {
    // Hash passwords for DB storage   
    $pwd1 = password_hash($login_name . $_POST['password_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    /*
        THIS WILL NEED TO BE UPDATED WHEN E-MAIL VALIDATION IS IMPLEMENTED
    */
    // Create query for inserting new data
    $add_user_query = "INSERT INTO `CMP_Users` (User_First_Name, User_Last_Name, "
        . "User_Login, User_Email, User_Password, User_Role, User_Created) VALUES "
        . "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";

    $mysqli_add_user = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $mysqli_add_user->set_charset("utf8");
    $stmt_add_user = $mysqli_add_user->prepare($add_user_query);
    $stmt_add_user->bind_param("sssssi", $first_name, $last_name, $login_name, $email, $pwd1, $role_value);
    $stmt_add_user->execute();


    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION['username'] = $login_name;
    $_SESSION['role'] = $role_value;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['fname'] = $first_name;
    $_SESSION['lname'] = $last_name;
    $connection->close();
    header('Location: http://www.collinmath.com/mathpages/index.php');
    exit();
}

// Close db connection
$connection->close();

}

// Check whether the user is already logged in
// and redirect them to the main user page if they are
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: http://www.collinmath.com/mathpages/index.php');
    exit();
}

?>
```

UPDATE:

So, I changed a bunch of the code and tinkered with the php.ini file but I'm still having problems.  When I look at my cookies, I see the cookie is there.  I see the file is created in the sessions folder and that the variables are set in that file, but there is still no session info when I do a var_dump.

My session_save_path and var_dump shows this:

```
/home/[myname]/sessions/

array(0) { }
```

and the file that is created in my sessions folder looks like this:

> username|s:7:"testerz";role|i:1;email|s:19:"email@email.com";fname|s:4:"First";lname|s:6:"Name";

Comment: Why is there no `session_start()` in the code?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem Fix:

*This is work in progress from the long comment discussion and will be updated as we go*

From what you've told me the logic process of your situation is impossible.

**RE: Your update:**
Then if the session is definitely being written then there are three possible options:

1) there is an `ini_set()` or a directory-local `.ini` file which is changing the session name so data from one directory is not being recognised in another, as they're looking in different sessions.

2) You have a spelling or casing issue of your `$_SESSION` keys.

3) `session_start()` has not been initiated.

**Furter debugging and Solution:**
Whenever you `var_dump` your session data, and it's turning up blank; add these lines:

```
 error_log(print_r(session_status()."<BR>",true)); 
 error_log(print_r(session_name()."<BR>",true));
 error_log(print_r($_SESSION,true)); //your original  output.
```

Add this code block to both your data-in page (create.php) and the destination page that is failing to show certain sessions.

If the above are always exactly the same (and they may be if , as you say,  some data does "work".

Then the answer is that you definitely absolutely have some lines in your code that change the session values. The symptoms look like you've got a screwed up REGEX `preg_` function somewhere. Again; use your PHP Error Log to check these things out.

## General Fixes:

- Quote your array keys; `$row[Login]` should be `$row['Login']
- Use a single MySQLi connection, of a single type
- That type should be the Object Orientated approach (`->`)
- Do not use `real_escape_string` for Object Orientated MySQL connections.
- Use [Multibyte PHP String functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)
- Use `UTF8mb4` MySQLi connection character sets, and the same in your tables and columns.
- Tidy up your code and your logic process, you've made a funtion but the function always runs so it has no benefit being a function - it may as well just be straight code.
- Don't use **globals**
- MySQL does not care about new lines so you don't need to concatenate the SQL strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm going to write a new function (it doesn't always get called -- it is only supposed to get called when the user gets to the page by clicking the register button) and see if that helps, then try to trace what is happening to the session.

Comment: Please write lots of new functions - your code does not separate concerns / is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this was the most random reason...

It turns out the problem was my php.ini file, but not for the reason I thought.  I had set the session.cookie_domain value to "collinmath.com" but needed to add a period to the beginning of collinmath.  I changed the session.cookie_domain value to ".collinmath.com" and it fixed the problem.  I have no idea why this worked, but it did.

Comment: This would not fix the issues you described where the session data *sometimes* displayed correctly.

Comment: What was happening was that the session domain was sometimes being stored as collinmath.com and sometimes being stored as www.collinmath.com.  I have no idea why it would do that, but when I added the period, it now always stores as .collinmath.com and works.

Comment: Yes but this has no relevance to the value of `username`. Anyhow, glad you found the issue `:-)`

Comment: I also made a lot of changes to the formatting of the code, per your suggestions.  I then got my login page to work and now I'm making the home screen.  It's coming along nicely now.